# Is the sample space for a stochastic process defined as the set of possible sample paths that may be realised by it?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

For example, were I to conduct an experiment where I constructed a stochastic process (defined at 2 time-steps) by tossing a coin twice. Would the sample space be defined as the set of possible outcomes for each toss
$$
\Omega = \{ H, T \}
$$
or the set of sample paths that may be taken by the process
$$
\Omega = \{ HH, HT, TH, TT \}
$$

Comment: In general in probability theory the sample space is really an abstract object, and all that matters is that we can build a probability space rich enough to define the joint distribution of all the random variables we care about. This can almost always be done for any reasonable request you can think of; strict-sense white noise is one of the only places where it can't.

Comment: That being said, the second answer is definitely the better one; the first case will not be rich enough to define a sequence of two flips, since there are only two distinct elements but two flips require at least four distinct elements to make sense.